# Теряются данные в массиве при передаче через сокеты

Tags: php, сокет

Доброго времени суток! Есть у меня клиент-серверная система на сокетах. С сервера клиенту передается ассоциативный массив данных размером 50кб. Массив кодирован в json формат. Передаю так:

```
socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

принимаю:

```
socket_read($socket, 120400);
```

Размер массива может быть разным. 
Так вот, проблема в том, что на стороне клиента некоторые поля массива оказываются null.
На стороне сервера поля не пустые, я проверял, Они содержат массив, в формате json.  
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какое-то странное поведение. Может быть проблема не в сокетах, а в кодировщике/декодировщике json ?

Comment: в смысле? вообще, я кэширую полученный массив - записываю его в txt файл не раскодируя - и там null

Comment: а если передавать данные кусками по 2кб с последующей склейкой?.. хттп протокол он такой коварный...

Comment: @deivan а при чем тут http ? @woland протокол какой ? (tcp/udp) или это unix_socket ?

Comment: вообще да, больше похоже на проблему кодировщика, т.к. скорее была-бы ошибка формата чем null, @woland - больше кода.

Comment: все, разобрался - я кое-что исправил и забыл перезапустить сервак